# How to cancel stylesheets rules for certain elements in page

Tags: html, css, jsx, antd

I using ANTD framework for building an app.
And latelly i noticed one small issue with one of ANTD elements when i import `antd-theme.css`
For some reasons that css overides rules for one ANTD elements and makes it look terrible.
I cannot refuse from using this css stylesheets because it's needed for other elements all over the app.
So it's imported in `index.js`
Also i cannot overide this rule which breaks ANTD element, because it's  stylesheet has 24844 lines.
And i will never find what exectly breaks it.
Believe me I tried:(
I was curiouse is there some how possible to make some element/elements ignore certain stylesheets?
Like something

```
<Radio style={{igonereCss}} />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can give your element a class that you define and it will use that over the other styles

```
<radio class="mystyle">
```

Then in your main css style sheet just define a style for that. It doesn't have to do anything, but it might override the styles that are happening elsewhere.

.mystyle {
}

Comment: Thank you for answer, unfortunatelly it didn't work:(

Comment: have you tried inline styling ?

Answer (score 0):

you can change style of specific component by overriding default class in your css file (you will get all the element classes from developer tool) for that element

```
.ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner{
   background-color:#fdfdfd !important;
}
```

as a result it will override the style globally, to override the style for specific component only just wrap the component in some div by giving class "test" and override the css

```
.test .ant-radio-checked .ant-radio-inner{
   background-color:#fdfdfd !important;
}
```

and it will update the style for specific component  only